# Android: MediaPlayer and AsyncTask Wakelock

Tags: android, android-asynctask, wakelock

I have an Activity that uses AsnycTasks to reset and restart a MediaPlayer after it finishes. This all works fine, but I want the MediaPlayer to continue playback even when the phone's screen is off. My first thought was a "PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK", and this works great until it is time for the MediaPlayer to re-start it using the AsyncTask, at which point it stops.

How can I keep the screen off but still keep my processes alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try android  [Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to play your Media files. You can also see [this](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html).